# What is /usr/sbin/service doing under a Docker container

Tags: ubuntu, service, docker

As far as I understand Docker containers do not have an init system, they only run whatever is specified in the Dockerfile's CMD part.

Yet, (for example in `FROM ubuntu:16.04`) when I do `/usr/sbin/service --status-all` I get a list of services, like in a real Ubuntu system.

What are those services doing? Is it just a leftover and they are actually not doing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upstart/service is just looking in /etc/init.d, which is populated by the package installers. Docker isn't modifying those. You can manually spawn process with a `service` command, but without init running, the OS won't spawn all the typical processes. And once you spawn a process, you still need to keep your pid 1 running to avoid having the container exit. The typical design of a container is to only run a single application, which would need to be run in the foreground, bypassing the Upstart/service and init.